# Angular JS 4 + clarity-angular ScrollTop hides Header

Tags: html, angular, scroll, scrolltop, clarity

In Angular 4 when router changes, the page don't Scrolls Top.

My solution is put a div with #top and in typescript I use ViewChild to scrollIntoView like

`<div #top></div>`

`import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';`

`@ViewChild('top') top: ElementRef;`

And when initiate and load all I need I call

`this.top.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();`

This working to PC, but in Mobile, the clarity header hides (`<clr-header>`), when I scroll top with mobile, scroll headers show again, but get a bad experience to user, I want header show everytime.

Remembering, header is on root, and all nested routes is inside "router-outlet", so my solution to Scroll Top in nested routes don't work to root.

I try use this command in root, but not works, the "scroll Top" just work in nested routes.

I already tried following commands:

`window.scrollTo(0, 0)` Not works

`document.body.scrollTop = 0` Not works

`this.document.body.scrollTop = 0` (using Angular DOCUMENT module) Not works

And many others... Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop ||document.body.scrollTop || 0
```

This will cover all the browsers and should work.